# cannot call value of non-function type 'OnAckCallback' in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io, swift3

in my `Swift2` I had a function that worked:

```
func connectToServerWithNickname(_ nickname: String) {
    print("CONNECTING TO SOCKET SERVER \(nickname)")
    socket.emitWithAck("connectUser", nickname)(timeoutAfter: 3) { data in
        print("CONNECTED FOR SURE")
    }
}
```

but when I moved my whole code to `Swift3`, I'm getting error:

```
cannot call value of non-function type 'OnAckCallback'
```

[image]

That method comes from the `socket.io` library and it looks there like this:

```
/// Sends a message to the server, requesting an ack. Use the onAck method of SocketAckHandler to add
/// an ack.
public func emitWithAck(_ event: String, _ items: SocketData...) -> OnAckCallback {
    return emitWithAck(event, with: items)
}
/// Same as emitWithAck, but for Objective-C
public func emitWithAck(_ event: String, with items: [Any]) -> OnAckCallback {
    return createOnAck([event] + items)
}

private func createOnAck(_ items: [Any]) -> OnAckCallback {
    currentAck += 1

    return OnAckCallback(ackNumber: currentAck, items: items, socket: self)
}
```

how can I fix my code so that it compiles?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue after updating to **Socket.IO-client-swift 8.2.0**.  Here is the change you need to make.

**Working Code**

```
socket.emitWithAck("connectUser", nickname).timingOut(after: 3, callback: { data in
    print("CONNECTED FOR SURE")
})
```

**Previous Code, causing error**

```
socket.emitWithAck("connectUser", nickname)(timeoutAfter: 3) { data in
    print("CONNECTED FOR SURE")
}
```